# Webstorm ubuntu отключить titlebar

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

Всем привет, как в webstorm на ubuntu выключить шапку с тайтлом? Чтобы кнопки управления окна были на одном уровне с меню.

Он занимает слишком много места и не несет для меня никакой пользы.
В vscode это можно сделать в настройках, в WS я такого не нашел.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать установив `Gnome Shell extension Pixelsaver`:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-pixelsaver
```

и так же нужно установить `Gnome Tweaks`:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

и дальше здесь можно отключить данную панель. У вас останется только три кнопки для действий над окном. Вот [первоисточник](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075690/on-ubuntu-18-04-can-i-hide-the-title-bar-and-still-see-the-close-minimize-maximi). [Вот](https://www.reddit.com/r/IntelliJIDEA/comments/e6v69u/is_there_a_way_to_hide_title_bar_in_intellij/) еще есть статья по вашему вопросу. [Вот](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/ee6xs4/disable_gnome_titlebar_for_application/) есть обсуждение где приведены те же программы что и у меня в ответе, и там говорится в первом комментарии. Так же есть способ:

```
File > Settings > Switch Decorate Mode
```

который тоже указан в данном обсуждении.

Comment: Спасибо, но, судя по комментариям это затронет все остальные окна, чего не хотелось бы, мне желательно убрать данную "фичу" только в WS

Comment: обновил ответ, там есть в WS вроде фича для этого дела :)